# Monitor Internet Usage on Ubuntu

Tags: networking, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you monitor internet download usage?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-internet-download-usage)

Any idea how one would monitor internet usage on a laptop to find out if any unauthorised program is making internet connections?

Answer (score 1):

Use nethogs :) 
Install it by typing `sudo apt-get install nethogs`. 
To start the app type: 
`sudo nethogs [network interface name e.g. eth0, eth1 or ppp0 etc.]` 
 To find this name use the command ifconfig and check which of the interfaces are associated with valid ip address..