# How to show dashboard for Micrmax 353G in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and Micromax 353G dongle for internet. Everything is working fine. But here I want to see my data used in that session and the balance data.

It is showing all the features in windows but as I am using ubuntu and I love this so I want all this in ubuntu. So is this possible to get a dashboard for Micromax dongle dashboard on ubuntu 12.04? Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Please elaborate on what dashboard means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want some sort of indicator to show network traffic totals.  As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1468/54187) you could use `vnstat`, although it is a command line utility.

Another option would be to combine `vnstat` and `indicator-sysmonitor`. For example if you want monthly totals in MiB to be displayed alongside other indicators install `vnstat`, then follow the instructions for installing `indicator-sysmonitor` [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/104883/54187), except use a  script like this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Tx (MiB):"$( vnstat -i wlan0 --dumpdb | grep "m;0" | cut -d ";" -f4)\
"--- Rx (MiB):"$( vnstat -i wlan0 --dumpdb | grep "m;0" | cut -d ";" -f5)
```

The output would look something like this: `Tx (MiB):41 --- Rx (MiB):3` and will be displayed alongside your indicators at the top of your screen, all you need to do is modify the script to display and format the data you are interested in.

You will need to change the `wlan` part of the script to what ever interface you are using, check `ifconfig`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I use dongle like the OP and the `-i wlan0` option should be `-i ppp0` (at least that showed me some output). However, on using the corrected script, I get everything as 0. `vnstat -i ppp0 -d` works.

Comment: Yeah everything show up as zeros for me initially as well, you don't get readings until vnstat runs for a little bit to populate its database. So your first monthly total will only be from the time you installed vnstat.

Comment: Got it. It is showing some value now. However, this is the client end data record. The OP wants balance. Subtracting total used from max available would be unreliable. How to do that?

Comment: I don't know how to do any better than what you suggested,(subtract total used from max available). Not a perfect answer I will admit but at least it gives you an idea of your monthly usage. :)

Comment: I read somewhere that we can connect to waytosms.com via terminal and send a message (using python script). If a similar case can be applied here, with the ISP's site, then we may have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The data tracking feature is native of the Windows application. As you use network-manager applet for connecting to internet, it isn't usable.

However, if you were to use wine, you may be able to get that application to work in Ubuntu. Although I must warn you, it may not work flawlessly in wine.

Also, ISPs provide such service online. Just create an account with the ISP's site, if allowed to do so, locate the link for such a service and bookmark it. Then you can simply click on it to find remaining data (saving the username and password in the browser).

Answer (score 0):

you may try gnome-system-monitor apps. under the resources tab you will see the amount of data that have been used under the network history but this only works for the current session as this will reset the moment you get disconnected.this works perfectly for me when tracking how much data i have received.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use **vnStat** to monitor your **bandwidth usage** on Ubuntu.

To install vnStat, run following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

Know more about vnStat, its official page is here http://humdi.net/vnstat/

and if you want easy guide on how to use it then you may go here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/11/vnstat-network-traffic-monitor/