# How to display network traffic in the terminal?

Tags: networking

how to display the actual network traffic (wireless) in a terminal?

Additionally: Is it possible to add this info to the chart of `top`?

Comment: Any solutions for the "Is it possible to add this info to the chart of `top`?" part? :)

Comment: @JanakaBandara check out [Glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances).

Answer (score 640, accepted):

Here are some nice tools in the Ubuntu repositories for command line network traffic monitoring:

### [bmon](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/net/bmon)

Shows multiple interfaces at once

[image: screenshot]

### [slurm](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/slurm)

Has nice colored graphs

[image: screenshot]

### [tcptrack](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/tcptrack)

A favorite. Tells how much bandwidth is being used and also what protocol (service/port) and destination the transmission is taking place to.
Very helpful when you want to know exactly what  is using up your bandwidth

[image: screenshot]

Comment: bmon is really cool!  has a graph like slurm but not colorful.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install bmon slurm tcptrack`

Comment: `nload` deserves mentioning for better separation of upload and download (also not colourful)

Comment: tcptrack is cool!

Comment: `sudo apt install ethstatus`

Comment: Haha this cracked me up: tcptrack displays activity in Bytes per second, and the 40Gbit link I set up overflowed the 32 bit integer... it flips between reporting `LUDICROUS` and a large negative value in the billions.

Comment: @StevenLu Please [file an issue](https://github.com/bchretien/tcptrack/issues)

Comment: Would be helpful to list the actual usage commands. E.g. how to track wifi with tcptrack.

Comment: bmon is the epitome of good design. it is powerful get extremely simple on default runs. pretty much maximizes the terminal usage.

Answer (score 258):

### [iftop](http://www.ex-parrot.com/%7Epdw/iftop/)

It's quite easy! Install "iftop" with:

```
sudo apt install iftop
```

Then run

```
sudo iftop
```

The application looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: To see anything, I have to run (Ubuntu using wifi):
$ sudo iftop -i wlan0

Comment: does `iftop` also record or log the network bandwidth from time to time? Currently I'm using both `vnstat` and `iftop` for different usage, and `vnstat` logs the bandwidth usage. It would be excessive and add more loads to my server if `iftop` does it too.

Comment: For easier selection of a traffic analysis program, editing to add a screenshot would be great :)

Comment: Definitely one of the most awesome tools ever seen so far

Answer (score 224):

### [Nethogs](https://github.com/raboof/nethogs#readme)

```sh
sudo apt install nethogs

sudo nethogs
```

The thing that's different and maybe is cooler about this one is that it shows traffic *per*  *process*, like the image shows

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Very useful utility, just note that you may need to take a few extra steps installing to make it work on 14.04 as https://askubuntu.com/a/729560/79176 describes.

Comment: For those with Debian Jessie who happen to come here, too:  A working version is in Backports:  `apt-get install nethogs/jessie-backports` ([you need to add jessie-backports first](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)).

Comment: "it shows traffic per process" exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. It answer the question which process is using up socket and bandwidth? How is this on Ubuntu 20.04? asking for a ...me.

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Works great on Ubuntu 20.04 @majorgear

Comment: running it but it does not seem to be able to tell I am connecting to site using Google App built in browser. No program details shown, just an ip address

Answer (score 90):

There is a nice tool called [speedometer](http://excess.org/speedometer/) that displays a graph in the terminal using Unicode block characters, colors, and even adds labels to each peak in the graph.

```
$ sudo apt-get install speedometer
$ speedometer -l  -r wlan0 -t wlan0 -m $(( 1024 * 1024 * 3 / 2 ))
```

[image: Screenshot after running the previous command]

It has several options, can monitor multiple interfaces, can show multiple graphs in several rows or columns, and can even monitor the download speed of a single file (by watching the file size on disk).

Comment: This is by far the nicest visiual graph i've ever seen in a plain text display.  I will be looking into the gui library by the same author now: http://urwid.org/  (source code and author: https://github.com/wardi)

Comment: @ThorSummoner: This is getting off-topic, but [urwid](http://urwid.org/) is the library used by the awesome [PuDB](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb) Python debugger.

Comment: This just sits at "waiting for <interface> to be created".

Comment: @felwithe That probably means you passed the wrong network interface name. Try changing `wlan0` in that command to `eth0` or to whatever is the name of the network interface in your system. See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125406

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia I did not; I checked that. I tried the other interfaces as well. That was all the time I had to fiddle with it. I was having network problems and had to find a tool that worked ASAP. I used one of the simple ones, and it turned out that the problem wasn't bandwidth anyway.

Comment: I've got no graph with a lot of question mark block on the terminal, what is missing?

Comment: @Unknown123 You're missing proper unicode/UTF-8 support in your terminal and/or in your shell environment locale settings.

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia Thanks for reminding me, I forgot such trivial things, I use Kali 2020.2, It has QTerminal 0.14.1 with Qt 5.12.5. There are three built-in supported unicode font that works with speedometer: Nimbus Mono PS,  MathJax_Vector, Courier 10 Pitch. After changing into one of that and adjust the font into 12pt, I was able to see the graph nicely.

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia How do I use for more than one adapter? I couldn't find any useful documentation, should I open multiple terminal or something like that?

Comment: @Unknown123 You just repeat `-r` and `-t` as many times as you want. You can also insert `-c` to start a new column. This is all described in `--help`.

Answer (score 61):

## [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/)

> IPTraf is a console-based network statistics utility for Linux. It
>   gathers a variety of figures such as TCP connection packet and byte
>   counts, interface statistics and activity indicators, TCP/UDP traffic
>   breakdowns, and LAN station packet and byte counts.
>
> Features
>
> An IP traffic monitor that shows information on the IP traffic passing
>   over your network. Includes TCP flag information, packet and byte
>   counts, ICMP details, OSPF packet types. General and detailed
>   interface statistics showing IP, TCP, UDP, ICMP, non-IP and other IP
>   packet counts, IP checksum errors, interface activity, packet size
>   counts. A TCP and UDP service monitor showing counts of incoming and
>   outgoing packets for common TCP and UDP application ports A LAN
>   statistics module that discovers active hosts and shows statistics
>   showing the data activity on them TCP, UDP, and other protocol display
>   filters, allowing you to view only traffic you're interested in.
>   Logging Supports Ethernet, FDDI, ISDN, SLIP, PPP, and loopback
>   interface types. Utilizes the built-in raw socket interface of the
>   Linux kernel, allowing it to be used over a wide range of supported
>   network cards. Full-screen, menu-driven operation.
>
> Protocols Recognized
>
> IP TCP UDP ICMP IGMP IGP IGRP OSPF ARP RARP
>
> Non-IP packets will simply
>   be indicated as "Non-IP" and, on Ethernet LAN's, will be supplied with
>   the appropriate Ethernet addresses.
>
> Supported Interfaces
>
> Local loopback All Linux-supported Ethernet interfaces All
>   Linux-supported FDDI interfaces SLIP Asynchronous PPP Synchronous PPP
>   over ISDN ISDN with Raw IP encapsulation ISDN with Cisco HDLC
>   encapsulation Parallel Line IP

Source http://iptraf.seul.org/about.html

## Installation

With `apt`:

```
apt-get install iptraf
```

Or download the source:

http://iptraf.seul.org/download.html

## Screenshots

Current Connections:

[image: tcp connections]

Current Ports:

[image]

Summary of all Interfaces:

[image]

Detailed per Interface:

[image]

Source http://iptraf.seul.org/shots.html

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04, looks like `iptraf-ng` has replaced `iptraf`.

Comment: Can `iptraf` display the speed for each TCP client @wisbucky? (a little bit like `tcptrack`)

Answer (score 39):

```
tcpdump -i eth0
```

That will give you a streaming information of all the data flowing from that interface (your ethernet card).  Similar to wireshark.

Use `ifconfig` to see a list of your machines interfaces.

Comment: This will certainly display the network information... Not a very user-friendly interface, nor does it have aggregate stats. Definitely think of this like wireshark.

Answer (score 36):

I think `ifconfig [interface]` will do that. Like:

```
gevorg@gevorg-TravelMate-3260:~$ ifconfig wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:de:89:52:71  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

gevorg@gevorg-TravelMate-3260:~$ ifconfig eth0
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:16:36:bf:92:e3  
          inet addr:192.168.10.100  Bcast:192.168.10.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::216:36ff:febf:92e3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:342765 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:306183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:373934806 (373.9 MB)  TX bytes:39111569 (39.1 MB)
          Interrupt:16
```

It shows **RX bytes:73934806 (373.9 MB)** and **TX bytes:39111569 (39.1 MB)**.

Comment: but this is only the over-all statistic for this session. I would see if the connection is active or not.

Comment: `netstat -t -u -c` ?

Answer (score 30):

If you are looking for something extremely simple, but still useful, try `ifstat`

```
$ sudo apt-get install ifstat
$ ifstat
       eth0               wlan0       
 KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out
    0.00      0.00      0.96      4.79
    0.00      0.00      0.04      0.14
```

It monitors all interfaces at once, printing a new line every second. Useful to pipe into another script, or to leave running and observe the bandwidth usage over time. Not as pretty as other tools, but it gets the job done.

There are some useful options listed in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/ifstat.1.html):

```
-z  Hides interface which counters are null, eg interfaces that are up but not used.
-n  Turns off displaying the header periodically.
-t  Adds a timestamp at the beginning of each line.
-T  Reports total bandwith for all monitored interfaces.
-S  Keep stats updated on the same line if possible (no scrolling nor wrapping).
-b  Reports bandwith in kbits/sec instead of kbytes/sec.
```

Comment: I love this command: `ifstat -zntS`, which outputs only network interface that are not null, with timestamps, without header showing periodically and with results in only one line (I love man pages).

Answer (score 27):

Another useful tool is sar.
Install it,

```
apt install sysstat
```

How to use it:

```
sar -n DEV  1
```

And Brendan's amazing graph guide:
[image]

#### References

- http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html
- [Linux Performance Observability: sar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN7Vg.png)

Comment: +1 for mentioning `sar`, which does the job and is included (and enabled) by default with most if not all distros.

Answer (score 25):

This is not specific to networking, but [Glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/) can display network traffic of different interfaces.

[image]

Install it with one of those commands :

```bsh
sudo snap install glances
sudo apt install glances
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 18, installing `glances` pulls in a lot of X11 and font related packages, which you may want to avoid when working with remote VMs / containers.

Answer (score 17):

According to [ifconfig man](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig):

> This program is obsolete!  For replacement check ip addr and ip
>   link.  For statistics use ip -s link.

So using **ip** command:

```
 $ ip -s link
```

We can get network stats:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    173654497900 26078946 0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    173654497900 26078946 0       0       0       0
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:34:56:78:90:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    3650412438854 399476618 0       2551849 0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    617437624480 321390259 0       0       0       0
```

Or

```
$ ip -s -h link

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    174G       26.1M    0       0       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    174G       26.1M    0       0       0       0 2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:34:56:78:90:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 addrgenmode eui64
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    3.65T      399M     0       2.55M   0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    617G       321M     0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Is there a way to filter for only one interface? e.g. who needs lo:? Or an unused eth? Just want the wifi adapter for example.

Comment: "show" display only on interface, e.g.:
$ ip -s -h  link  show lo

Answer (score 16):

Install ’vnstat’ it can show traffic for an interface.  You can install some plotting packages to get some nice graphs.

Comment: This seems to be the best option to get a usage history: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-internet-data-usage

Answer (score 13):

Also you could use `iftop` utility

Answer (score 9):

Ifstat is good tool and it will give you all the interface network usage with respect to time.

```
sudo apt-get install ifstat
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another possible tool is called `nload`.
http://linux.die.net/man/1/nload

Similar to `slurm` or `bmon`, but a little more simplistic.

Comment: This tool works awesome on ARM macos with `brew` in 2024

Answer (score 5):

And this is a blog showing a list of command to monitor bandwidth:

http://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/

***UPDATE:***

I've been using ***NetHogs*** for about two months. It shows you total bandwidth usage.
With the following setting you can additionally get bandwidth usage for each program

`sudo nethogs -v 3`

Answer (score 5):

There is another tool called [bandwhich](https://github.com/imsnif/bandwhich)

[image: gif]

Comment: This is great if you also want to see the addresses of each process. The only drawback for me is it's currently doesn't include the PID of each process.

Comment: Nice looking. Some kind of "fade out" feature would be cool, otherwise I recommend the -t option to see totals.

Answer (score 5):

A powerful tool `bpytop` like a Swiss army:

Install:

```
sudo apt install bpytop
```

List interfaces:

```
ip -br -c a
```

Monitor all resources:

```
bpytop
```

Also, you can customize your output schema with numbers:

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

[image]

Comment: See also `btop`, another rewrite that appears to be newer and faster. Also available in the default Ubuntu repos it seems: `sudo apt install btop`

Answer (score 4):

I recently discovered `wavemon` which can easily be installed using `apt-get install wavemon`.

This tool provides information especially on the signal level of the wireless network.

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick without needing to install anything special and without needing to be root either:

```
for i in {1..60};do echo `ifconfig eth0 | grep X.pa`;sleep 1;done
```

replace `eth0` with whatever interface you want to look at.

sample output:-

```
RX packets 7838573576 bytes 5261871317174 (4.7 TiB) TX packets 5420075700 bytes 2937680670358 (2.6 TiB)
RX packets 7838574080 bytes 5261871493163 (4.7 TiB) TX packets 5420076058 bytes 2937680745341 (2.6 TiB)
RX packets 7838574496 bytes 5261871573887 (4.7 TiB) TX packets 5420076379 bytes 2937680870613 (2.6 TiB)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`nettop`](https://github.com/Emanem/nettop) is another option (not in the standard linux repos).

To build clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/Emanem/nettop.git
```

Install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev build-essential libpcap-dev
```

And build the binary:

```
make
```

Run with:

```
sudo ./nettop
```

<sup>Btw, macos has a built-in utility called `nettop` which does the same thing but has more features.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Get your answer direct from the process: `cat /proc/net/dev`
easily filtered by line to get a specific interface, e.g.
`cat /proc/net/dev | grep eth0`

```
Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
 face |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
    lo:  176979    1003    0    0    0     0          0         0   176979    1003    0    0    0     0       0          0
  eth0: 58424096 208513    0  428    0     0          0         0 53857573  355931    0    0    0     0       0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also [conky](http://conky.sourceforge.net/documentation.html).

You might have the package listed in your system's currently used repositories. Try running:

```
sudo apt-get install conky-all
```

Some basic configuration info: [Ubuntu Community Docs: Configuring Conky](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky#Running_.26_Configuration). CAUTION: The info on that site may be out of date, so please verify the steps listed there apply to your system.

Of course, a basic conky is very boring to look at, so here's a good conky theme to get you started:

[conky_themes](https://github.com/zagortenay333/conky_themes): Just follow the instructions on that page for setup; to install a particular theme, copy the `.conkyrc` file from the corresponding folder for the theme in the `.harmattan-themes` folder to your home directory.

Then, edit the file according to the instructions on the linked page.

**TIP**: Modify the file *after* copying it to your home folder, this way you get to keep the original unaltered files in case you need to re-copy the `.conkyrc` file for a theme.

Answer (score 1):

For me, [Slurm](https://github.com/mattthias/slurm) worked well:

[image]

Install:

```
sudo apt install slurm
```

List interfaces

```
ifconfig
```

Monitor interface (change eth0):

```
slurm -i eth0
```

Comment: Note: This isn't the same as the HPC resource manager SLURM (which is present in the `slurmd` apt package).

Answer (score 0):

[VnStat](https://humdi.net/vnstat/) is a fully-featured, command line-based program to monitor Linux network traffic and bandwidth utilization in real-time, on Linux and BSD systems.

Install:

```
sudo apt install sysstat
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [vnstat](https://humdi.net/vnstat/) and [sysstat](http://pagesperso-orange.fr/sebastien.godard/) are two different packages