# top like utility for network activity/ports by process

Tags: networking, monitoring, top

I'm looking for a utility to continuously monitor network traffic by process.

Something like `top` but instead of focusing on CPU/memory, I would like to see TCP and UDP ports and throughput for the most network-active processes.  I imagine a regularly updated screen with headers like:

```
PID   USER  PROTO  PORTNO   Kbps   STARTTIME  COMMAND...
```

The closest I could find are `atop` and `lsof -i`. `atop` shows aggregate network activity in the main screen (not by process). Hitting `N` for a network focused view gives:

```
Kernel module 'netatop' not active or no root privs; request ignored!
# When run under sudo, so how do I install the 'netatop' kernel module ?
```

`lsof -i` shows the processes holding the ports, but no throughput/activity.

`sudo watch netstat -Wtunape` is another good option. It includes IP addresses, ports (both local and remote) and even connection states, but doesn't include throughput and process start-time.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/257263/how-to-display-network-traffic-in-terminal and http://askubuntu.com/questions/2411/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-eating-up-my-bandwidth

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `nethogs`  a small 'net top' tool to continuously monitor network traffic by process.

It has  PID, USER, PROGRAM, DEV,  SENT and RECEIVE column.

Comment: Thanks! nethogs seems the closest to what I'm looking for.  I wasn't aware of it.  Wish it would have displayed a PROTO, PORT and process STARTTIME too.  This is especially needed for the `unknown TCP` entries...

Comment: It is very useful command. I am looking for something similar. A command having the same output in addition to the CPU and Mem details ?! any recommendations ?!