# Network Interface Traffic Visualizer

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, internet, bandwidth

I have multiple interfaces active at a time, I want to visualize the bandwidth in/out from the interfaces on my PC. I know iptraf does this without visualization.

So, far the [closest tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257263/how-to-display-network-traffic-in-terminal) I have found is bmon but it visualizes only one interface at a time. I want visualizations of all interfaces.

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  bmon - shows multiple interfaces at once and Use terminator (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) to see the graphs of different interfaces.

```
sudo apt-get install bmon
```

Comment: What does `Use terminator` mean in this context? When I hit that key combination in `bmon` nothing happens. When you say `Use bmon - shows multiple interfaces at once`, how do you make bmon show multiple interfaces at once?