# how much bandwidth is currently used by network

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-monitoring

In windows there was a status info for the connection like how much data was used in the session .

is there some thing similar for that

Comment: This does not answer your question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/257263/how-to-display-network-traffic-in-terminal (all terminal based) Also:  see System Monitor in System Administration.

Comment: this is a terminal based , i search for GUI application or if it's already in the system , however speedometer seems ok with me , thanks for quick help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Resources tab  of the System Monitor (`gnome-system-monitor`) has a section for network usage:

[image]

System Monitor is installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to install jnettop , iptraf or iftop . All are terminal commands to see the current network traffic.