# Find out what network data is being sent/ recieved

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-monitoring

I have recently had a data cap put on my mobile wifi subscription, in order to make sure I am paying for what I use and not more I am trying to track my usage. Having looked around the best way I have found to do this is to use the built in Ubuntu system monitor. I have discovered that even when not knowingly using any applications that are connected to the internet, my network is showing a small amount of data being uploaded and downloaded.

Is there an easy way to find out where this is coming from, what’s using it, and is there a nicer data monitor that perhaps stores results so I can look back over them at the end of the month?

Comment: Does this solve your problem - http://askubuntu.com/questions/257263/how-to-display-network-traffic-in-terminal