# Ubuntu Server bandwith monitoring

Tags: networking, bandwidth

I run a program on ubuntu server that runs 24/7, I'm after a program that can measure the amount of bandwith it uses (Download and Upload seperate if possible), I need to be able to see it capturing in real time, aswell as view how much has been uploaded/downloaded.

I'm not a Noob to Ubuntu Server, but I'm not advanced either, so something "Easyish" to install/configure/use would be great.

It also, has to be command line based, as I run a VPS where this will be used.

Any recommendations will be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: There's a question in the related section: http://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-internet-download-usage?rq=1 with a few suggestions. I'll also add `iftop` to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I also do not consider myself a great specialist and the only monitoring tool that seemed suitable for me was [Anturis](http://www.anturis.com), that is super simple and is able to monitor the servers. It has an agent which penetrates and monitors every block or file and collects the data, warns about potential threats and offers troubleshooting. Have a look.