# How to know how much data is consumed in ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, internet

I have recently installed ubuntu 14.04 .I used to have windows 7 on my laptop .

In order to keep a track on how much data I have consumed ,I used to have a software called **NETWORX** which also helped me to decide a quota on my everyday usage.

Is there any similar application in ubuntu to track of my consumption?

Where can I get it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you monitor internet download usage?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-internet-download-usage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `System Monitor` for a general high level overview.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

BitMeter OS is an open source bandwidth monitor with features similar to Networx. It has a Web interface and a command line interface as well. It also has an experimental desktop client. ".deb" packages can be downloaded from http://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeteros/downloads and installed with gdebi package installer or from the command line using (64-bit version)

```
$ sudo dpkg -i bitmeteros_0.7.6-amd64.deb
```

See http://codebox.org.uk/pages/bitmeteros for more information on the application.