# nethogs shows 0 KB although I have traffic

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-monitoring, nethogs

I am running a network related program that performs TLS handshakes with many hosts. I ant to monitor the network traffic so I used `nethogs`. It shows 0 KB.

```
NetHogs version 0.8.5-2

PID USER     PROGRAM                    DEV        SENT      RECEIVED       
  ? root     unknown TCP                            0.000       0.000 KB/sec

  TOTAL                                                 0.000       0.000 KB/sec
```

I have previously run this program and nethogs was showing me information about the network traffic. What is the problem? How to see the ongoing/outgoing traffic? Are there alternative tools?

I use Ubuntu 18.04.
The command I entered:

```
sudo nethogs
```

I also tried with the adapter name that I obtain using ifconfig:

```
sudo nethogs enx9cebe8b0d86a
```

Comment: You could try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097746/how-to-get-rx-and-tx-traffic-data-using-shell-script/1097775#1097775).

Comment: You could try `vnStat`. I've used it for years with great success: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1459/how-can-you-monitor-total-internet-data-usage-across-reboots/846455#846455